# Template Member Function to Write to Output Iterator

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, virtual, member-functions

I thought I would be smart and create member functions that accepted output iterators. This way, I could avoid returning a collection or taking a collection by reference. For example:

```
template <typename TOutIterator>
void getHeaderNames(TOutIterator destination);

template <typename TOutIterator>
void getHeaderValues(std::string const& name, TOutIterator destination);
```

These functions will write their results to whatever iterator is passed in. This way, I don't have to worry whether I'm writing to a set, vector or ostream.

Now I don't feel so smart. I want to make these functions virtual so I can stub out the implementation in test. Unfortunately, template member functions can't be virtual, which makes sense.

Is there a way to keep these functions generic (write to anything) and allow them to be virtual at the same time? I want to avoid writing everything to a vector only to turn around and write it to standard out or whatever.

Let me know if I need to explain my situation more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [type erasure](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html) to manipulate polymorphic iterators, like the [`any_iterator` proposed by Thomas Becker](http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/any_iterator.html) (and later [implemented in Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/range/detail/any_iterator.hpp)). You would end up with something along those lines:

```
typedef any_iterator<
  std::string, // Value
  Writable,    // Access
  Forward,     // Traversal
> StringOutputIterator; // can represent any output iterator accepting strings

virtual void getHeaders(StringOutputIterator destination);
```

The idea of type erasure is to have a common base class for a set of otherwise unrelated types (which happen very often in C++, due to the use of templates). For instance, `std::function` applies this idiom to callable objects, by allowing the manipulation of function pointers, functors or lambdas in a similar way.

Comment: Is there a specific header in Boost where any_iterator is located?

Comment: @TravisParks: Check the link in the answer. However, the `any_iterator` in Boost.Range is used as an implementation detail for `any_range`, I'm not sure it is meant to be used by the library users. You can try using it anyway, or come up with your own version (drawing inspiration from Becker's and Grove's implementation).

Comment: I had another thought: I could create a header collection class that had begin/end methods. Those methods would still need to return an iterator type that didn't expose the implementation details. any_iterator would be much less indirection.

Answer (score 0):

One way to keep them generic, and I usually see this in practice, is two overload a stream output operator (if it makes sense) or take an `std::ostream&`.

Of course it depends on your exact situation: Are you writing an algorithm for which iterators make more sense? Or just want to dump an object's content?

Comment: Internal to my object, there is a map<string, vector<string>> representing the header key/value pairs returned from an HTTP request. I want to allow iterating over the keys and each key's values without exposing the underlying data structure (a multimap would work, too, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, and I didn't want to add Boost to my project... so I decided not to use iterators at all.

I ended up using a `std::function` instead:

```
void getHeaderNames(std::function<void(std::string)> destination);

void getHeaderValues(std::string const& name, std::function<void(std::string)> destination);
```

Then, instead of `std::back_inserter`, I provide a lambda that executes `push_back`:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
getHeaderNames([&](auto name) { v.push_back(std::move(name)); });
```